# Should paginated content have unique meta tags?

Tags: meta-tags, pagination

I have a category page that leads to an additional 100 pages. For example:

`www.example.com/category` <- this is my category page

`www.example.com/category-2.html` <- this is paginated content

My question is, do I need unique meta tags for each and every page, or is there any way that my category page's meta tags can be used by all the numbered pages?

Answer (score 9):

For my paginated results, what I did was dynamically add page numbers and a result index. For example:

```
<meta name="description" content="Page 3 of 11, nike shoes 30 to 40 out of 300. 
Buy good quality nike shoes blah blah">
```

In the above example, page 3 of 11 and pages 30 to 40 out of 300 would dynamically be generated using PHP or similar. This is OK I believe.

If you don't want to use new meta descriptions for each page, then use:

```
rel="next"
```

and

```
rel="prev"
```

Here's a couple of resources worth looking at:

[Google's Guidelines on Paginated Content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=en)

[The MOZ Blog - Pagination: Best Practices for SEO & User Experience](http://moz.com/blog/pagination-best-practices-for-seo-user-experience)

Comment: You also need to make this for page title? Or it would be sufficient only the description? the problem with the title is that will create a long phrase. Stackoverflow for example will ignore completely pagination in metas:  https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=php&sort=i&pg=3