# What to do with titles/keywords/description for multiple pages

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, ecommerce

*First: I'm not looking for specific solutions, I'd like this to be a bit more broad to support other peoples similar situations.*

I'll keep it short (unless more info is requested). I'm managing a webshop and there's a problem I keep getting, Google Webmasters gives me something along these lines:

- 3000 duplicate titles
- 3000 duplicate descriptions

95% of these are my product overviews. Some finctional examples:

- example.com/products/watches (page 1)
- example.com/products/watches (page 2)
- example.com/products/watches (page N)
  **Or**
- example.com/products/bracelets (page 1)
- example.com/products/bracelets (page 2)
- example.com/products/bracelets (page N)
  **Etc**

I have no good solution thusfar to fix this. **These pages are dynamic**, I might have:

- /men,watches,rings,brandname (page 1 - N)
- /watches (page 1 - N)
- /brandname (page 1 - N)
- /woman,bracelet,silver (page 1 - N)

As you can see, might be a brand, might be a category, or both. I can't just take a snippet of a brand, because that means every page containing that brand will have duplicate titles again. I cant take some text from the (first) category, because all combinations where that category is first will have, again, the same title.

I'm out of ideas. I have a canonical tag to indicate multiple pages, I have `link rel="prev|next"` in my `head` and I can't seem to find any good topics about this.

**How can I fix duplicate titles for multiple product overview pages?**

Comment: Might help: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/63582/should-paginated-content-have-unique-meta-tags/63594#63594

Comment: Oh, thats about exactly what I'm looking for, thanks :) Such an easy solution, never thought of it