# Changing pagination, and having more sections per page

Tags: seo, search-engines, googlebot, pagination, negative-seo

I'm upgrading an old website, from having 25 results per page (40 pages), to having 50-100 per page (5-10 pages)

This will change the pagination, and maybe affect search engines in a bad way.. So I'm wondering, how I could go about this the best way?

Redirect all requests to old page id's to the first page? Or re-calculate intervals and find the new correct page? (that would be messy and very advanced for me)

Comment: Why not allow the user to choose how many to display per page?

Comment: @AbuNooh I'm aiming at super simplistic design, without too many buttons/options/choices etc. Before = pagination. Now = just back/forward. And with fewer pages for users to go through

Comment: I am assuming that this is a result page with links to other pages... while 100 is a fine number, you may be reaching a limit. There are sites with some pages with far more links on select pages, however, using mechanization it may not be wise to go beyond this limit. Just saying... ;-)

Comment: @closetnoc Yes. I said 50-100, but it's actually just 50 ;)

Comment: I am the kinda guy that would chose a random number just to have some fun... but that is just me!

Comment: @closetnoc A random number where?

Comment: To keep the same structure in search engine indices. You could just add an extra get parameter like show=50. All you'd need is a select input field. That way you keep the current structure and add what you need. No need to change or any negative seo impact.

Comment: @AbuNooh Ah yes, I see. That could work. But I have to consider canonical hints then, somehow. I don't use queries in url, only masked as folders

Comment: But if the old url setup was mysite.com/content/8/ (where 8 is the page number), then what?

Comment: Do you have page numbers in the url? If you use js to trigger select input without a submit button then you could only make it available for users and no need to worry about search bots cos most won't be able to select it anyway.

Comment: @AbuNooh I want to change the default display from 25 to 50 per page, completely without user choice in that matter. Can we go back to SEO topic ;)

Comment: A random number of results... ;-) Alternatively, you could respond with 48-49 or 51-52 and see if anyone notices... Okay. I am a bit of a jokester sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of recalculating the first item on a page, **use a `from` instead of a `page`**:

> example.com/articles/from-40

If you switch to more/less items in a page, you still start at 40.

**To prevent "duplicate titles/descriptions"** and such, indicate pages using the `rel="next/prev` :

> <link rel="prev" href="/articles/from-20" />
>    <link rel="next" href="/articles/from-60" />

**Do not use noindex/nofollow**. Noindex isn't very optimal, just let Google decide about that, and nofollow is terrible, you really do want them to follow the anchors on your pages and index the items.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done in the past with a similar situation without any issues in URLs (404, canonical etc).

So I added a dropdown with a bit of js to take away the submit button like this:

```
<select onchange="window.location.href = (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" name="rows">
<option selected="selected" value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="chapter.php?cid=7&amp;page=1&amp;rows=10">10 Per Page</option>
<option value="chapter.php?cid=7&amp;page=1&amp;rows=25">25 Per Page</option>
```

So if you have a URL like:

```
mysite.com/content/8/
```

that would remain, all your pages would remain as far as search engines are concerned. And only users who have javascript enabled which is most humans/browsers can select and view however many per page. And for those users the URL would look something like this:

```
mysite.com/content/8/50
```

and so on. And yes google bot is advanced and is able to view with js enabled so that would new URLS will also get indexed in that case you'd just add, like you say some canonical hints. Have a [look here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/63582/should-paginated-content-have-unique-meta-tags/63594#63594) for some tips.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to use `noindex` for sub-pages archive. like `/page/2/`, `/page/3/` & so on. (Search engines don't like it either)

Eventually, your sub-pages will be removed & you won't have to worry about what happens when you change `per page` items list.

Use `Infinite Scroll` to load sub pages content. That should also improve UX.

Comment: nofollow is terrible to use! It means that if a bot reaches this page, it will NOT follow any anchor to any link!

Comment: +1 for using `rel` attribute. My bad on adding `nofollow` (edited now) - but I personally prefer using a `noindex` directive on these less important sub-pages, Google anyway decides by themselves what to index. :)

Comment: These subpages are very relevant and important ;)

Answer (score 0):

Pagination is almost never worth it from either a search engine or user experience perspective.    Just eliminate that as a feature altogether.

#### Users

Less than 10% of users usually click to page 2.   Less than 1% of users usually click to page 3.     I've never measured a situation where enough users rely on pagination to warrant keeping it.

#### Search engines

Page rank falls off very quickly in a series of pages.  Especially when page 1 links to page 2 via "next" and page 2 links to page 3 and so on.   By the time you get to page 3, there is so little link juice available that search engines will never rank page 3 content.

Titles and meta descriptions of pagination are usually so similar you also run into duplicate content issues.   I have tried writing different titles and descriptions for the first three pages of pagination but I've found that effort has very little payoff.

They also wont push any juice to into the pages you are listing in the pagination beyond page 1.   It is far better to have your detail pages link to each other directly (similar products, you might also be interested in, people who looked at x also looked at y).

Get rid of your pagination and redirect everything back to page 1.